# Type of output of this AND Gate

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, logic-gates, push-pull, open-drain

I am unable to find whether the output of this [IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g08.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1690948738226&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fsn74lvc1g08) is a push-pull output or an open drain output.

I didn't notice either words in the datasheet. Hence, can someone help me to tell which output type is the output of this IC.

Comment: datasheet section 9.1

Comment: @jsotola, yes went through that. But not sure how to identify in that paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's push-pull (that is the default). However if there is any question, you can also look at the source and sink capability of the output. An open-drain or open-collector output would have only leakage in the high state:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, when a datasheet has the high-level ans low-level output parameters, then it is assumed to have a push pull output, am i right?

Comment: Open drain output should have a leakage specification. eg. https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AHC1G09.pdf Ioz maximum 2.5uA at up to 85°C.

Comment: @Freshman It is not the _existence_ of output parameters, but the _magnitude_ of the output current, which gives you the indication.

Comment: @thebusybee, can you please let me know what should the magnitude of output current be for the different outputs?

Comment: @Freshman As Spehro pointed out, a push-pull has comparable sourcing and draining capabilities, for example as shown in the screenshot. An open-drain would only drain relevant current for an active low output and has a by magnitudes lower off-state current else. Isn't this logical?